# Performance load testing tools that enable automated load tests

Tags: api, rest, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to find out load testing tools for testing non UI based REST api's. It is required that the load tests can be automated preferably using octopus deploy or tfs. I am  completely new to the Microsoft side. Please let me know options.

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise license of Visual Studio includes performance testing that can be executed via TFS.

[Load Testing Visual Studio Online & TFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edglas/archive/2013/11/27/load-testing-visual-studio-online.aspx)